# Pull access denied for aws_beanstalk/ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to deploy a sample docker beanstalk app via cloud-formation. 
I have application version defined as

```
BeanstalkApplicationVersion:
   Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
   Properties:
     Description: Initial Version
     ApplicationName: !Ref BeanstalkApplication
     SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket: !Join ['-', ['elasticbeanstalk-samples', !Ref "AWS::Region"]]
        S3Key: docker-sample.zip
```

I am getting `Error response from daemon: pull access denied for aws_beanstalk/ubuntu, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

The docker file of beanstalk sample seems to be

```
FROM aws_beanstalk/ubuntu:12.04

# Add sample application
ADD application.py /tmp/application.py

EXPOSE 8000

# Run it
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/tmp/application.py"]
```

I checked on my roles for instances,they are using `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` which seems to be correct.

Not sure what's going on here, if  `aws_beanstalk/ubuntu` actually does not exist or it's a permission issue or AWS hasn't updated their samples.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is an image that someone built on their local machine, and used it for another image, Try just using the stock ubuntu image

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
```

Comment: I can't edit the docker file. It is coming from aws samples.

Comment: then you can tag the image so your machine can use it
`
docker tag ubuntu:12.04 aws_beanstalk/ubuntu:12.04
`

Comment: That code comes from the elasticbeanstalk samples bucket and I think that is managed by AWS. I can't edit the docker file. See example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html 
The docker sample zip https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-samples-us-east-1/docker-sample.zip